# No Schema Validation on Confluent Cloud

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry, confluent-cloud

I am using confluent cloud and currently i want to prevent messages with bad schema to ingest in my kafka topic. For that i am using schema management feature of confluent where i want to validate if the message is not matching the specified schema it should be rejected. I can produce this on confluent local but no rejection can be seen on cloud.

1. Does cloud currently support schema validation?
2. If not, do we have to implement it via kafka streams to validate schema ourselves?
3. Any reference to their official documentation for above answers? Or any document guiding this scenario for confluent cloud (not local) would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: run into the same issue where ccloud does not seem to support it. sending ccloud some email trying to get some clarification on it.

ccloud kafka topic update foobar --config confluent.value.schema.validation=true
Error: CCloud backend error: 1 error occurred:
 * error updating topic configurations for foobar: invalid configuration entries map[confluent.value.schema.validation:true]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not properly described in their documentation. After contacting support got email describing:

> At this time, we don't support broker side schema validation in
> Confluent Cloud, but the good news is it on the roadmap for furture
> support.  I don't have an ETA for the release to share at this time.
>
> I also see Robert Yokota (an engineer who also works in Confluent's
> Schema Registry team) confirm the same as well in the github issue
> you've provided.
>
> Hope this helps.  We'll be proceeding with case closure shortly.
>
> Thanks,

Github issue referred above can be seen [here](https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/issues/1599)

Answer (score 1):

Broker-Side Schema Validation on Confluent Cloud seems has been supported now. Please check [here](https://docs.confluent.io/cloud/current/sr/broker-side-schema-validation.html#cloud-schema-validation).